# Making a java program that gives the number of distinct substrings of a input

Tags: java, substring

I need help making a program in java that will take an string input of letters (**no spaces**) and then output  the number of **distinct** substrings.

*Example Output:*

*Input string to test: abc -
“abc” has 7 distinct substrings.

Input string to test: aaa -
“aaa” has 4 distinct substrings.*

I am completely lost and any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please put the code that you have tried for this problem.

Comment: Don't just post your assignment here. At the very least: try.

Comment: How do you know the number of outputs? You can see some pattern right? Write logic in white paper.. Try converting to your java program.. Then when you're stuck , come here

Comment: "aaa" substrings are "a", "aa", "aaa" so its three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is homework, here is a guide.

- Create a Set of String.
- add each combination to the set.
- get the size of the set.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick Java solution

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        combination("abc");
        System.out.println(set.size());
    }

    public static HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>();

    public static void combination(String s) {
        combination("", s);
    }

    private static void combination(String prefix, String s) {
        if (s.length() > 0) {
            String str = prefix + s.charAt(0);   // print here if you want
            set.add(str);
            combination(prefix + s.charAt(0), s.substring(1));
            combination(prefix, s.substring(1));
        }
    }

}
```